# Oracle Forms freeze when I try to maximise and minimize the browser

Tags: sql, oracle, oracleforms

In Oracle forms, when am trying to minize and maximize the screen multiple times, the form freezes and does not allow me to enter data. 
Following are the steps I have performed.
1.Launch the Oracle form
2.Restore Browser to Minimize 
3.Drag browser and try to adjust the size by moving slowly back and forth
4. Screen will froze won’t let you enter anything

Is it got something to do with the set_window_property?
Anyone's help is highly appreciated

Comment: Is the screen really frozen? Or is it just the case that you lose focus, so you can't click with the mouse in a field. Try to click on the forms screen to activate the forms window and then with you tab key to move between fields and try to enter data, if this works you lost you focus and your screen ain't frozen.

Comment: yes, the screen is frozen. Am unable to select the form nor put a cursor on any fields after I try to minimize and maximize the screen multiple times.